# Not Able to Verify ITR1

Tags: html

I got an error message while verification of my ITR1.
[#/ITR/ITR1/TaxPayments/TaxPayment/0/DateDep: string [NaN-NaN-NaN] does not match pattern ([12]\d{3}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01]))];#;Please contact the developer of your utility with the error key

Please help me to solve this

Comment: Safari browser has that issue. Try filling in the date for the challan under tax self assessment using chrome browser. And it should work.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. I downloaded the JSON after filling online and then used offline utility to file the returns.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).